# How do you install an MPEG-4 AAC decoder plugin for Linux Mint Debian Edition?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, mp4

How do you install an MPEG-4 AAC decoder plugin for Linux Mint Debian Edition?  In Ubuntu they say it's sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras but LMDE uses Debian. Anybody knows?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you use

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo apt install mint-meta-codecs` (extracted from [Linux Mint forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=235762))

Comment: i would strongly suggest avoiding the mint-meta-codecs package, which requires installing adobe-flashplugin